# Get request triggered by js

Tags: javascript, django, url, get

I will explain what functionality I need in my django app on this example:

*User see list of cars and click "detail" button next to nice Mazda3, this action redirects him to the other page with URL like www.myapp.com/cars/detail/mazda3 where he can see additional information about car loaded from database. Also if he access this URL directly it should work without previous js call.*

I'm begginer and my plan after some search is to

- in js function trigger GET request, including car model in url
- in urls.py map base of this url '/cars/detail/' to view function
- in views.py parse car model from url and render page

Problem is that I'm not sure this is correct way or if I should choose different approach. Also is GET request necessary (I've read that synchronous request should not be triggered in js) or should I just redirect to wanted url?

Comment: why you need just just make an `a` tag pointing to `www.myapp.com/cars/detail/mazda3` and clicking it will get you there. The point of using GET from js is if you want to avoid page reload, in that case use react or something instead of plain js or jquery

Comment: Got your point, I just wasn't sure if its proper way for django application to hardcore urls in like this.

Comment: no you shouldn't hardcore urls in django templates. use url names, If you are not sure how to do that show me your urls.py, I will tell you what to do

Comment: I didn't get it to work with this line but right now its url(r'edit_project/<str>', views.edit_project_form, name='edit_project_form')

Comment: also I need to later use this attribute so I'm going to check it further, some slug: method come out during googling so it may help, will update later

Comment: ok, first unless you are using some super old version of django, don't use url(), path path() and re_path(). Everything else looks fine. Now in your templates do this`<a href="{% url 'edit_project_form' my_project %}" >` NOT this `<a href="/edit_project/my_project/">`